# Ansible: how to get the calculated value of key "content" displayed into the playbook output

Tags: ansible, jinja2, padding

I am a beginner to ansible.

How can I get the content of the csv file printed in my shell?

I tryed to register the calculated value of `content` key and to display it via

```
    - ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ csv_content }}"
```

in another task, but I cannot see it into my playbook output.

```
 vars:
    current_date: "{{ '%Y-%m-%d' | strftime }}"

  tasks:

    - name: Dump results to /tmp/myfile.csv
      copy:
        dest: /tmp/mycsv_{{ '%Y-%m-%d' | strftime }}.csv
        content: |
         
          {% for host in hosts_list %}
          {% ---things--- %}
          {% set idm=host.inventory_hostname.split('_')[0].split('-')[1] %}
          {% set idm_padded = '%03d' % idm|int %}
          {% ---things--- %}
          {{ [idm_padded, --things-- ] | map('trim') | join(';') }}
          {% --things--- %}
          {% endfor %}
      vars:
        hosts_list: "{{ ansible_play_hosts | map('extract', hostvars) | list }}"
      register: csv_content
      run_once: yes
     

    - ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ csv_content }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to get the content from the `copy` task, reverse your logic: render the content into a variable *first*, then use that variable as the argument to the `content` key in the `copy` task:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        csv_content: |
          {% for host in hosts_list %}
          {% set idm=2 %}
          {% set idm_padded = '%03d' % idm|int %}
          {{ [idm_padded, "things" ] | map('trim') | join(';') }}
          {% endfor %}
      vars:
        hosts_list:
          - foo
          - bar
          - baz
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ csv_content }}"

    - name: Dump results to /tmp/myfile.csv
      copy:
        dest: mycsv_{{ '%Y-%m-%d' | strftime }}.csv
        content: "{{ csv_content }}"
      run_once: true
```